# How to push vectors into queue<vector<int>> using loop?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I want to push vectors into my queue using the following code:

```
queue<vector<int>> q;

for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
    vector<int> t(3,-1);
    q.push(t);
}

vector<int> p = q.front();
q.pop();
```

Is this correct? I'm worried that since `t` is only defined inside the loop it will get destroyed as soon the loop is over. So will the pushed vectors still exist in the queue after the loop is over?

I had a similar code which was giving segmentation fault, so I thought this might be the problem.

Comment: Imagine you are pushing integers to the queue instead of vectors. Are you worried now? Why or why not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this correct?

Yes. When used with the default `std::deque` backend, `std::queue::push(const T&)` copies its argument into the underlying container through its internal `std::deque` instance. When the argument goes out of scope, that's fine, `q` owns its own copy of it.

Note, however, that

```
q.push(std::move(t));
```

would be more efficient, as this requires only move-constructing a vector instance, which is cheaper. This is again safe as you don't use `t` after moving it to the queue.

Comment: I do believe using queue::emplace would be more beneficial here as there is no temporary object needed. So no copy / move operation would occur

Comment: @Rostin You're right. Could be, however, that the creation of the vector to store in the queue is more involved than what was posted. But anyway, for the example shown, `emplace_back`  is indeed a more appropriate choice.

Answer (score 2):

As @lubgr mentioned in his answer this is correct,
the container will have a copy of the argument when using `std::queue::push`

Using `std::queue::emplace` is more efficient as it pushes a new element into the container so no temporary is created and no copy/move operation would occur

You tagged this question with C++14 standard, `std::queue::emplace` is available since C++11

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/emplace